# Setting new class variables inside a module

Tags: ruby, class-variables

I have a plugin I have been working on that adds publishing to ActiveRecord classes.  I extend my classes with my publisher like so:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  publishable :related_attributes => [:taggings]
end
```

My publisher is structured like:

```
module Publisher

  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:extend, ClassMethods)

    @@publishing_options = [] # does not seem to be available
  end

  module ClassMethods

    def publishable options={}
      include InstanceMethods

      @@publishing_options = options

      # does not work as class_variable_set is a private method
      # self.class_variable_set(:@@publishing_options, options)

      # results in: uninitialized class variable @@publishing_options in Publisher::ClassMethods
      puts "@@publishing_options: #{@@publishing_options.inspect}"

      # ...
    end

    # ...

  end

  module InstanceMethods

    # results in: uninitialized class variable @@publishing_options in Publisher::InstanceMethods
    def related_attributes
      @@publishing_options[:related_attributes]
    end

    # ...
  end

end
```

Any ideas on how to pass options to publishable and have them available as a class variable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am presuming that you want one set of `publishing_options` per class. In that case you just want to prefix your variable with a single `@`. Remember the class itself is an instance of the class `Class` so when you are in the context of a class method you actually want to set an instance variable on your class. Something like the following:

```
module Publishable
  module ClassMethods
    def publishable(options)
      @publishing_options = options
    end

    def publishing_options
      @publishing_options
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
end
```

Then if ActiveRecord::Base is extended as follows:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, Publishable
```

You can do:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  publishable :related_attributes => [:taggings]
end

class Other < ActiveRecord::Base
  publishable :related_attributes => [:other]
end

Note.publishing_options
=> {:related_attributes=>[:taggings]}

Other.publishing_options
=> {:related_attributes=>[:other]}
```

Comment: I was reluctant to use an instance variable to store my options in, but that worked for me.  I think I was just thinking in the wrong terms about which instance was being created at the time.  In the InstanceMethods module, I am accessing publishing options by
    self.class.publishing_options

Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: Yep, adding an instance method that does `self.class.publishing_options` is the way to go in order to make your publishing options available to an instance of `Note`

Comment: I just found this question five years later and it saved me hours of headache - thank you so much, @mikej!

Comment: Point to note: Class instance variables are not inherited. so basically subclasses of this will not have these vars available. This will cause problems when you call some super method and that method is expecting some value of that variable